# How to get the 1st transaction date then separate it to another column

Tags: mysql

I want to separate the 1st transaction date of every client to another column. Im not good at explaining. Hope the image below is enough to clarify my question..

[image]
I want to generate a result like in the picture. **I just edited this picture for the reference of the result that I want.

this my sqlfiddle ---> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bebf5/1

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i checked image but what is concept to move date either in begin or cr?

Comment: if the date is the 1st transaction date for every client. it will belong to the "BEGIN" column, if it is not it will belong to "CR" column.

Comment: so it is a mere initializer

Comment: @Strawberry. maybe they just want to identify easily the 1st transaction date.

Comment: @john it's easy either way - who are 'they' and what do you mean by 'maybe'?

Comment: @Strawberry our thesis instructor.. We are just doing what they want so that we can pass our thesis. I dont know why he want that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe PN_NO represents client. We would need to perform ordering of rows based on PN_NO and Pay Date columns. It is needed to identify first transaction date.  Please try below query.

```
SELECT
  SCHED_NO, 
  PN_NO, 
  PAY_PRIN, 
  PAY_DATE,
  CASE WHEN PN_NO_Rank=1 THEN PAY_DATE ELSE '' END AS BEGIN,
  CASE WHEN PN_NO_Rank <>1 THEN PAY_DATE ELSE '' END AS CR
FROM
(
SELECT 

  SCHED_NO, 
  PN_NO, 
  PAY_PRIN, 
  PAY_DATE,
  @PN_NO_Rank := IF(@current_PN_NO = PN_NO, @PN_NO_Rank + 1, 1) AS PN_NO_Rank,
  @current_PN_NO := PN_NO 
FROM PAY_SCHED
ORDER BY PN_NO, PAY_DATE ASC
) AS Temp
```

Comment: thnx your a great help.

Answer (score 0):

That should help:

```
SELECT SCHED_NO, PN_NO, PAY_PRIN, PAY_DATE, 
CASE WHEN pay_date = (select min(pay_date) from pay_sched where pn_no=ps.pn_no) THEN pay_date ELSE NULL END as "BEGIN",
CASE WHEN pay_date = (select min(pay_date) from pay_sched where pn_no=ps.pn_no) THEN NULL ELSE pay_date END as "CR"
FROM PAY_SCHED ps order by pn_no, pay_date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bebf5/26/0